# With MathJax \[ \] math, floated elements float with the next paragraph instead of the current one

Tags: html, css, css-float, mathjax

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/tRRtY/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>$$ float</title>
<script
type="text/javascript"
src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=default">
</script>
<style type="text/css">
p {
    background: lightblue;
}

span.dollar {
    float: right;
    background: maroon;
    color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Example 1</h1>
<p class="math">
\[
(a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2
\]
<span class="dollar">$$</span>
</p>
<p>Foo</p>

<h1>Example 2</h1>
<p class="math">
\(
(a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2
\)
<span class="dollar">$$</span>
<p>Foo</p>

</body>
</html>
```

In the first example, I see the the `$$` text floated beside the second paragraph. However, I want it to be floated beside the first paragraph. How can this be done?

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I explain in my answer on the [MathJax user's forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mathjax-users/H7ogO9ghHG8), the solution is to put

```
<br style="clear:both">
```

between the `<span class="dollar">$$</span>` and the `</p>` that follows.  That forces the paragraph to continue to the end of the floating element before the next paragraph starts.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is using inline MathJax commands.

Example:

With square brackets the equation will appear in a new line:

```
\\[ frac{1}{2} \\]
```

But if you use parenthesis then your equation will be in the same line:

```
\\( frac{3}{4} \\)
```